# CXF Bus for a client within a web service - memory leak

Tags: web-services, memory-leaks, jboss, cxf

I have a Jax-WS service that needs to call out to another JAX-WS service with a CXF client.  Because this client requires additional WS-* features, such as WS-Trust, I create a new CXF bus.

```
private void startupBus() 
{
    // if the bus is already active, shut it down to pick up any endpoint changes
    if (bus != null) {
        bus.shutdown(false);
    }

    bus = BusFactory.newInstance().createBus();

    // Add logging interceptors to log messages to and from the services it calls
    ...
    inBusLog.setPrettyLogging(true);
    outBusLog.setPrettyLogging(true);
    bus.getInInterceptors().add(inBusLog);
    bus.getOutInterceptors().add(outBusLog);
    bus.getInFaultInterceptors().add(inBusLog);
    bus.getOutFaultInterceptors().add(outBusLog);

    BusFactory.setThreadDefaultBus(bus);

    ...//create service proxy with this bus, setup STS client parameters, etc
}
```

Both my bus and my service proxy are static instances, and because I want to modify my parameters externally, this method re-runs once per day.

I'm seeing a memory leak, however, when this service stays up and running for a few days.  Its relatively slow, so I cannot pinpoint if its something to do with my bus/proxy rotation logic, or if its elsewhere.

Is there any additional cleanup that needs to be done on the proxy( such as a `java.io.Closable.close`? ) or am I incorrectly configuring/managing my CXF bus instance?

Comment: which version of cxf you are using and the server?

Comment: CXF 2.6.8  & JBoss EAP 6.1.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe it will be useful for the future
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/JBWS/Apache+CXF+integration#ApacheCXFintegration-BusselectionstrategiesforJAXWSclients

```
try {
  Service service = Service.create(wsdlURL, serviceQName);
  MyEndpoint port = service.getPort(MyEndpoint.class);
  //...
} finally {
  BusFactory.setThreadDefaultBus(null);
  // OR (if you don't need the bus and the client anymore)
  Bus bus = BusFactory.getThreadDefaultBus(false);
 bus.shutdown(true);
}
```